# Timestamps in QuestDB Python time.time() Not working

Tags: python, timestamp, questdb

ı am building a database in  QuestDB.

ı set up a table and one column is timestamp.

docs about table = https://questdb.io/docs/guides/working-with-timestamps-timezones/

timestamp column is converting automaticly 1623167145123456 to '2021-06-08T16:45:45.123456Z'.

doc say :
***The native timestamp format used by QuestDB is a Unix timestamp in microsecond resolution. QuestDB does not store time zone information alongside timestamp values and therefore it should be assumed that all timestamps are in UTC. The following example shows how a Unix timestamp in microseconds may be passed into a timestamp column directly***

when ı try to send this column

```
time.time()
```

it's not working.

Python time.time() = 1657105707.8171313
doc input = 1623167145123456

when ı delete this blank in python time.time() and send this to timestamp column
output is :

```
2495-02-11T11:02:24.069445Z
```

what should ı do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out `int(time.time() * 1000000000)`

It is working for me in [this example](https://github.com/javier/questdb_dataset_utils/blob/main/tfl_dataset.py) to send open data from TFL to QuestDB

Comment: it's really annoying actually. there is no library for microsecond ?

Comment: I couldn't find one. But the QuestDB team is working on an official client for python, and once it is released it should be much simpler to deal with ILP ingestion